# Attack RSA with very big module ($n$) and very small $e$ (7)

Tags: rsa

As an exercise I'm given an RSA to attack. I have the module ($n$), the public exponent ($e$) and a single ciphertext ($c$).

For this particular case, $n$ is VERY big (5 thousand digits more or less), but the public exponent is small ($e=7$).

I know that, as $m \ll n$, this can cause no use of the module operation ($m^7\bmod n = m^7$). I tried reversing it doing $c^{1/7}=m^{7\cdot1/7}=m$ but this is not working.
It might be that $m^7 \bmod n \neq m^7$. What can I do in this case?

What am I missing/misunderstanding?

EDIT

I was given an hint: "Big $n$ is useless with small $e$". I assume it has more to do with the exponent rather then $n$.

Comment: I think you mean 16 Kib (kibibits)? 16K decimal digits would indeed be *very* large.

Comment: Could (c+k*n) be a power of 7 for a small value of k?

Comment: Changed the question. It's a 4931 decimal digits $n$

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any small k that makes that true

Comment: Is this problem supposed to be easy (e.g. a Capture-the-Flag challenge)?  Unless the problem was designed with a specific weakness in mind, it's likely to be infeasible to solve.

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to have a vulnerability and it surly has a solution

Comment: If you've already tested $c+kn$ for small $k$, the most likely vulnerability would be that $n$ is easy to factor (maybe it's prime, or a bunch of small primes times a large one, or two large primes *extremely* close together)..

Comment: I have edited the question.I've tried to factorize $n$ with no success. I also don't think it is made of close primes as the exercise seems suggesting another solution